# Joining 2 tables with 1 table referencing twice on 2 different column

Tags: sql, oracle, left-join

I need help on this particular problem I have

Lets say given these 2 tables contain these fields

```
Table A

Account_no | expiry_date

Table B 

Id | Account_no | Account_no
```

Am I able to join the results together

Such that it becomes

`Id | Table A | Table A`

Given that some of the account no in table B is nullable. An example of this is

```
Table B

1 | 123 | 124

2 | 222 | null
```

Comment: Show us some sample table data for both tables, and also the expected result. ([mcve])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outer join `Table_A` twice and give each join a different table alias:

```sql
SELECT b.id,
       b.account_no1,
       a1.expiry_date AS expiry_date1,
       b.account_no2,
       a2.expiry_date AS expiry_date2
FROM   Table_B b
       LEFT OUTER JOIN Table_A a1
       ON ( b.account_no1 = a1.account_no )
       LEFT OUTER JOIN Table_A a2
       ON ( b.account_no2 = a2.account_no )
```

So, if you have your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_a (
  account_no  NUMBER
              CONSTRAINT table_a__account_no__pk PRIMARY KEY,
  expiry_date DATE
);

CREATE TABLE table_b (
  id          NUMBER
              CONSTRAINT table_b__id__pk PRIMARY KEY,
  account_no1 NUMBER
              CONSTRAINT table_b__account_no1__fk
                REFERENCES table_a ( account_no ),
  account_no2 NUMBER
              CONSTRAINT table_b__account_no2__fk
                REFERENCES table_a ( account_no )
);

INSERT INTO table_a ( account_no, expiry_date )
SELECT 123, DATE '2020-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 124, DATE '2020-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 222, DATE '2020-01-01' FROM DUAL;

INSERT INTO table_b ( id, account_no1, account_no2 )
SELECT 1, 123, 124  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 222, NULL FROM DUAL;
```

Then the query outputs:

> ```
> ID | ACCOUNT_NO1 | EXPIRY_DATE1 | ACCOUNT_NO2 | EXPIRY_DATE2
> -: | ----------: | :----------- | ----------: | :-----------
>  1 |         123 | 01-JAN-20    |         124 | 01-JAN-20   
>  2 |         222 | 01-JAN-20    |        null | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=690424228de7023b093fefb9ce3a044b)*